# Recognising a drawn line using neural networks in a web app

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, image-recognition

Basically, I was weighing up some options for a software idea I had. The web app thing is a bit of a constraint on the project, so I'm assuming I would be writing this in js.

I need to create a drawable area for the user, which is okay, allow them to draw and then compare the input to a correct example. This is just an arrow, but the arrow can be double headed (normal point arrow) or single headed (half an arrowhead), so the minute details are fairly important, as is the location.

Now, I've read around for a few hours or so, and it seems to be that a good approach is to downsample the input so I am just comparing a couple of pixels. I am wondering though if there is a simpler way to achieve what I want here, and if there are good resources for learning what I feel is a very basic implementation of image recognition. Also having never implemented something like this, I'm a little worried about the little details of something like this, like speed; obviously feedback has to be fairly quick.

Thanks.

Comment: To expand, my current idea on approach is to recognise that an arrow has been drawn, confirm the type, create a box which encapsulates its coordinates, compare it to some correct answer which has the boxes in the right place and return something.

Answer (score 0):

Use openCV. It already has the kind of use cases you want (location, style etc. of the image). There are many other open source libraries but not many as robust as this.

After that you have to decide all the possible images you want to make as the standard image, then get training examples for each of these standard images (each of these std images would be your one single class).

Now use the pixels as the features (openCV will do it for you with minimum help) and do your classification training. Not you have to provide these training images and have at least a good amount of training images for each class. Then use this trained classifier to classify the images that are drawn by your users. You can put GUI on top of it to adapt to your needs that you posted above.